# Meteor(React) : Redirect from server-side(from Meteor.methods)

Tags: redirect, meteor, server-side

I want to redirect to url within app(not external url) from server-side. Flowrouters, window.location are for client-side redirection. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can log the user out, which will notify the client, and take them to the logged out screen (I think you can register for a logged off event in the client)

Comment: Sorry Mate I am not getting you're point. Can you please elobrate?